# enum property inconsistent accessibility

Tags: c#

I am new at CSharp, and do not understand what is the problem.

```
public abstract class Player
{
protected Behaviour fBehaviour;
public Behaviour FBehaviour { get; set; }
```

the error says Error    6   Inconsistent accessibility: field type ... is less accessible than field ...

I've tried changing everything, but nothing worked.

Comment: What environment you are using to write code? In Visual Studio each error have index ([CS0052](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/997yz02a.aspx) in your case), and each common error code have article on MSDN explaining most common case when error is shown. (You may want to look at Output window and pick Build to see full text of errors instead of looking at Error window).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that class Behavior is not public, but Player is and is trying to expose it as public.

Change Behavior to be public.

Comment: and the answer is still the same

Comment: yes it is the same... 5 hours of programming results in these kinds of mistakes thank you